# Accessing items in a dump of dictionary objects in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a strange dataset from our customer. It is a `.json` file but inside it looks like below

```
{"a":"aaa","b":"bbb","text":"hello"}
{"a":"aaa","b":"bbb","text":"hi"}
{"a":"aaa","b":"bbb","text":"hihi"}
```

As you notice, this is just a dump of dictionary objects. It is neither a list (no `[]` and comma seperator between objects) nor a proper `JSON` although the file extension is `.json`. So I am really confused about how to read this file.

All I care about is reading all the `text` keys from each of the dictionary objects.

Comment: What is the actual programming question? Have you tried reading the file in? Did it work? If not,  why? Etc...

Comment: Sounds like [JSONL](http://jsonlines.org/), or some ad-hoc close thing.

Comment: You have to know what the format is if you want to implement something that will work for any input. We can guess what the format is from what you showed just as correctly as you can guess the same, but _maybe_ it is better to ask those who created the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [51]: [json.loads(i)["text"] for i in open("file.json").readlines()]
Out[51]: ['hello', 'hi', 'hihi']
```

Use list comprehension, it's easier

Answer (score 2):

This "strange dataset" is actually an existing format that builds upon JSON, called [JSONL](http://jsonlines.org/).

As @user655321 said, you can parse each line. Here's a more complete example with the complete dataset available in the list of dicts `dataset`:

```py
import json

dataset = []
with open("my_file.json") as file:
    for line in file:
        dataset.append(json.loads(line))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read it line by line and convert the lines to JSON objects and extract the needed data `text` in your case.

You can do something as follows:

```
import json
lines = open("file.txt").readlines()
for line in lines:
  dictionary = json.loads(line)
  print(dictionary["text"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not a single JSON file, you can read in the input line by line and deserialize them independently:

```py
import json
with open('my_file.json') as fh:
   for line in fh:
      json_obj = json.loads(line)
      keys = json_obj.keys() # eg, 'a', 'b', 'text'
      text_val = json_obj['text'] # eg, 'hello', 'hi', or 'hihi'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting the content by `\n` then using json to load each dictionary? something like:

```
import json

with open(your_file) as f:
    data = f.read()

my_dicts = []
for line in data.split():
    my_dicts.append(json.loads(line))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import ast
with open('my_file.json') as fh:
     for line in fh:
         try:
             dict_data = ast.literal_eval(line)
             assert isinstance(dict_data,dict)
             ### Process Dictionary Data here or append to list to convert to list of dicts
         except (SyntaxError, ValueError, AssertionError):
             print('ERROR - {} is not a dictionary'.format(line))
```